# count the elements of array in a loop

Tags: php

i all i need littel help
php 7.2 debian 9 apache2.4
 i have array 2d first is this
ok my ask is not clear
I put you the complete structure of my array

```
 array[result]
    array[allproduct]
    array [1]=>
               [product] name product
               [quantity] 25
               [price]  1.25 usd
               array [1.1] => sale by month
                             liste of 12 months
   array[2] =>
               [product] name product
               [quantity] 20
               [price]  2.00 usd
               array [2.2] => sale by month
                             liste of 12 months
   end array allproduct
   end array result
```

i print my data in foreach but I can not count
nbr product totlal quantity all product  average price and 1.1 average on 12 months

```
foreach($data["results"]["allproduct"]  as $key=>$result){
// print all element in table
}
```

I find all of these elements in this form

```
0 product quantity price
```

I want to count the total number of my table 1 product and quantity
I do not want to use Table 1.1 in my release but just the average
so my final outing will be

```
0 product quantity price
1 product quantity price
end foreach
total product 2 total quantity 45 sales 3.45 average
```

for exemple
all try send this
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable
thank for your help

Comment: Your question is not clear, update it

Comment: Sorry but you do `foreach($data["results"]["allproduct"]` and I can't see any `$data["results"]["allproduct"]` in your example? Can you edit your question and add your `array` with data in php format? And the output is not clear, you want to sum all `quantity` and have the `average price` according to each product price? So if you have `quantity = 5 / price = 1 AND quantity = 5 / price = 2` you want `total quantity = 10 and average price = ((5 * 1) + (5 * 2) ) / total quantity = (5 + 10) / 10 = 15/10 = 1.5` ?

Answer (score 0):

i think this will work :

```
$counts = [];
$counts = array();
foreach($data["results"]["allproduct"]  as $key=> $result)
{
   $counts[$result['$key']][] = $result['price'];   
}

foreach ( $counts as $key => $item ) 
{
  $counts[$key] = array_sum( $item );
}
```

Comment: Why do you think this will work? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.